# Union of Bases spans the sum of subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, solution-verification

I did a proof involving the sum of subspaces being finite-dimensional. It is as follows:

Given two finite-dimensional subspaces $W_1$ and $W_2$ of a vector space, $V$, show that $W_1+W_2$ is also finite-dimensional.

Proof.

Suppose $A = \{a_1,...,a_m\}$ and $B = \{b_1,...,b_n\}$  are bases for $W_1$ and $W_2$ respectively. Then, $A\cup{B} = \{a_1,...,a_m, b_1,...,b_n\}$ is a finite set.

Choose some $v \in V$ s.t. $v=w_1 + w_2$, where $w_1 \in W_1, w_2 \in W_2$. Then, for $c_1, ..., c_m, d_1, ..., d_n \in F$,

$$v =c_1a_1 + ... + c_ma_m + d_1b_1 + ... + d_nb_n = span(A\cup{B})$$

As a result, $v\in span(A\cup{B})$.

We conclude that $W_1+W_2 \subset span(A\cup{B})$

$W_1 + W_2$ is finite-dimensional.

QED.

Is this proof correct? If so, please let me know. If not, please let me know what error(s) I made.
Thank you!

Comment: In the 'we conclude' part you should have $W_1+W_2\subset \text{Span}(A\cup B)$

Comment: Oh yeah! Silly mistake. Thanks for noticing!